# SurveyJS MatrixDynamic maxRowCount based on an API's length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, surveyjs

I've been trying to make the length of my API as the value of the maxRowCount of the json file, but I can't seem to figure out how do i do it. This is my json file

```
export const json = {
  "completedHtml": "<div style=\"color: #1e4b57; text-align: center; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; padding-bottom: 75px;\">Thank you for submitting your adoption application. We will notify you once we have reviewed your application. Thank you.</div>",
  "pages": [
    {
      "name": "Front Page",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "html",
          "name": "Opening",
          "html": "<div style=\" text-align: justify;\"><p>At Purrfect Adoption, we are delighted that you are considering adopting one of our beloved pets. Our mission is to find loving and forever homes for our furry friends, and your interest in adopting makes a significant difference in their lives.</p></div>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "P11",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "matrixdynamic",
          "name": "Q14-A",
          "title": "How many pets are you willing to adopt?",
          "isRequired": true,
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "Q14-AA",
              "title": "Pets",
              "cellType": "dropdown",
              "isRequired": true,
              "choicesByUrl": {
                "url": "http://localhost:5000/pet-count",

              },
              "storeOthersAsComment": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Q14-AB",
              "title": "Pet Count",
              "cellType": "text",
              "isRequired": true,
              "inputType": "number",
              "min": 1,
              "max": 100
            }
          ],
          "cellType": "text",
          "rowCount": 1,
          "maxRowCount": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "showQuestionNumbers": "off",
  "startSurveyText": "Apply Now",
  "pageNextText": "Next",
  "completeText": "Submit",
  "firstPageIsStarted": true
};
```

This is the React side,

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Model } from "survey-core";
import { Survey } from "survey-react-ui";
import "survey-core/defaultV2.min.css";
import { json } from "./json";
const survey = useRef(new Model(json)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPetCount = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/pet-count");
        const availablePets = response.data;
        const petTypes = availablePets.split(',').map(type => type.trim());
        const question = survey.getQuestionByName("Q14-A");
        if (question) {
          const column = question.getDisplayValueName("Q14-AA");
          column.choices = petTypes;
        }
        question.maxRowCount = petTypes.length;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching available pets:", error);
      }
    };

    getPetCount();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Survey model={survey} />
  );
export default AdoptionApp;
```

I tried all sort of solution but I can't seem to figure it out. I want to use the API's length like in the              "choicesByUrl": {
"url": "http://localhost:5000/pet-count",
} which I was able to use it for the choices, but I cant seem to find any forum or things that will change the maxRowCount based on an APIs length